# Unresolved reference: launch in viewModelScope

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I am trying to call a suspend function using viewModelScope.launch in which "launch" is showing as Unresolved reference.

Here is build.gradle

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mynotes"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.appCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$rootProject.activityVersion"

    // Dependencies for working with Architecture components
    // You'll probably have to update the version numbers in build.gradle (Project)

    // Room components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"

    // Kotlin components
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$rootProject.coroutines"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$rootProject.coroutines"

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0'

    // UI
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$rootProject.constraintLayoutVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.materialVersion"

    // Testing
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$rootProject.coreTestingVersion"
    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.espressoVersion", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$rootProject.androidxJunitVersion"
}
```

and the ViewModel.kt

```
package com.example.mynotes

import android.app.Application
//import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class NotesViewModel(application: Application) : ViewModel() {

    private val repository : NotesRepository
    val allNotes : LiveData<List<Notes>>

    init {
        val dao = NotesDatabase.getDatabase(application).getNotesDao()
        repository = NotesRepository(dao)
        allNotes = repository.allNotes
    }

    fun deleteNotes(notes: Notes) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.delete(notes)
    }

}
```

In the function deleteNotes "viewModelScope.launch" is showing Unresolved reference: launch but there is no error while building the app but my app crash while running.

Comment: Share your crash log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of the way you are declaring the variable, since you are declaring it as a direct function, you can try the following:

```
fun deleteNotes(notes: Notes) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.delete(notes)
    }
}
```

It's possible the issue is related that when the method is declared and stored in memory, the scope hasnt been assigned yet.

Comment: That would not be possible with a function. The `=` in a function is just an alternate syntax.  The function is still only evaluated when it is called. Regardless, the viewModelScope is available even at instantiation time.

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using?

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1"
```

Try to use this case is different.

Try to invalide cache and restart if still not recognized